# How To: Fill the Font Awesome 4.x Lightbulb

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

Currently, the only way to 'fill' the lightbulb icon from Font Awesome (I'm dealing just with version 4.x here) is to apply the fill color as the background. But then you wind up with an ugly box around the icon.

NOT OPTIMUM! (Also ugly!)

I'm curious if anyone knows a way to fill the bulb - just the bulb, and not the background. And not the outline lines of the bulb. The idea is that I'd like to display lightbulbs of different colors, where the bulb is filled in, as the outline colors are honestly not as readily apparent.

The bulb icon in question:
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/lightbulb-o/

Comment: download the icons you want, edit in inkscape, and apply following the directions on fontawesome's site for locally hosted icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```css
.fa-lightbulb-o {
  position: relative;
}

.fa-lightbulb-o:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -.214em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
}
```

And here's a way to turn it on/off:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.fa-lightbulb-o');
el.onclick = function() {
  el.classList.toggle('lit');
}
```

```css
.fa-lightbulb-o {
  position: relative;
}

.fa-lightbulb-o:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -.214em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
}

i.fa-lightbulb-o {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 2rem;
  display: flex;
}

.fa-lightbulb-o:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .42s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.fa-lightbulb-o:after,
.fa-lightbulb-o:before {
  font-size: 10rem;
}

.lit:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 8px);
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 7em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> &#187; <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i> &#171;
```

... and the `<svg>`, in case you want to change the color. remember it needs base64 encoding to be used inside `url()` cross-browser.

```html
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 1792 1792' style='enable-background:new 0 0 1792 1792;' xml:space='preserve'>
    <path fill='yellow' d='M1181.5,792.3c13.7-14.7,23.8-25.7,30.5-33c45.3-52.7,68-112.7,68-180c0-48-11.5-92.7-34.5-134c-23-41.3-53-75.2-90-101.5c-37-26.3-78-47-123-62c-45-15-90.5-22.5-136.5-22.5s-91.5,7.5-136.5,22.5s-86,35.7-123,62c-37,26.3-67,60.2-90,101.5c-23,41.3-34.5,86-34.5,134c0,67.3,22.7,127.3,68,180c6.7,7.3,16.8,18.3,30.5,33s23.8,25.7,30.5,33c85.3,102,132.3,201.3,141,298h228c8.7-96.7,55.7-196,141-298C1157.7,817.9,1167.8,806.9,1181.5,792.3z'/>
</svg>
```